# Is there any method to store a docx file as separated pages in the mysql database using php?

Tags: php, mysql, docx

I need to store a docx file into mysql database where every page is store in one column. is it possible to do it?

Comment: Is it a "yes" or "no" answer help you in any way?

Comment: you should store link instead